# What is inside the "trigger" of a DC drill switch

Tags: pwm

[image: inside a DeWalt cordless drill]
What is (most likely) inside of the switch of a cordless drill?

I'm guessing there is:

1. A mechanical switch to select direction
2. A MOSFET
3. Protection for the MOSFET: diode? Another MOSFET?
4. A PWM generator ([555](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/555_timer_IC#Astable)?)
5. A potentiometer

Is that correct and complete? Or is something else used?

I've checked 4 very different switches (from 9.6-18V drills) and was surprised to find they all worked on a single 3.7V cell, albeit on/off only, jumping from slight noise but no movement to "full on". Would have to be a logic-level MOSFET for that behavior, I think.

Comment: That is essentially it. A PWM driver. But I seriously doubt they use a 555.

Comment: Similar [question](https://www.diynot.com/diy/threads/wiring-of-trigger-circuit-for-cordless-drill.259590/) with a photo of the trigger group internals.

Answer (score 1):

According to comments: YES, that's all.

[The thread](https://www.diynot.com/diy/threads/wiring-of-trigger-circuit-for-cordless-drill.259590/) linked to by [nick-alexeev](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/7036/nick-alexeev) mentions that at the end of the 'trigger' pull, full power is connected directly, bypassing the PWM driver and MOSFET for efficiency - that may explain the 'on/off" behavior on low voltage, as a logic-level MOSFET still seems less likely, at least on >9.6V drills.